# SAP localization of strings that are hardcoded

Tags: import, localization, sap

Does anybody know how SAP and other ERP companies deal with localization issues such as Import values? To give a specific example: If I am trying to translate the message: "Value has to be either 'Y' (Yes) or 'N' (No)", we are running into a problem here when translating it to German, since the values Y or N are hardcoded in the source code. Now I dont know how this issue would be handled in SAP, Netsuite, Epicor, Microsoft Dynamics Ax. Do they go all the way to change their source code every time they hit an issue like this or something similar, for every language?

I hope i made myself clear, since i am not a programmer at all ...

Comment: Epicor stores it as a boolean, and as far as I know doesn't take a Y/N keyboard input. Typically input would be via a checkbox or a properly localised dialog box.

Comment: Not a programming question. Needs more focus. Please explain how you translate because the answer may depend on the tools you are using. The only possible answer to your question should be posted by an expert who knows the main ERP applications on the market. Concerning SAP ECC (not talking of the other ERP SAP B1), you can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I expect they leave the value in place and just translate the meaning.  So instead of

```
'Y'(Yes) or 'N'(No)
```

It would be

```
'Y'(Ja) or 'N'(Nein)
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you ask the question?

Normally you don't enter an answer, you use Screens/Popups with Buttons.
An example with function module POPUP_TO_DECIDE_WITH_MESSAGE:
[image: POPUP_TO_DECIDE_WITH_MESSAGE]

So it does not matter, what you write on the button. The technical result of pushing a button is the same for each language.

---

I used in similar situations

```
(Y)es or (N)o          <- English
(J)a  oder (N)ein      <- German
(O)ui ou (N)on         <- French
(S)i  ??               <- Spanish/Italian
```

and I test with:

```
IF answer CA 'YyJjOo'.
*  Yes branch
ELSEIF answer ca 'Nn'.
*  No-Branch
ELSE.
  WRITE 'Please repeat answer'(001).
ENDIF.
```

`CA` means 'contains any' and checks if a letter is used. So I can check for different languages and the usage of small letters or capitals.

Up to now it worked with the languages I need.
If a language would have a 'n' for yes, then you may combine your test with `SY-LANGU`.

```
IF ( SY-LANGU = 'XX' and answer CA 'Nn'). 
...
```